# A generalization of Baumslag-Solitar groups

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, linear-groups

I am wondering about the following generalization of the group $B_{1,2}=\langle a,b\, |\, bab^{-1}=a^2\rangle$:
$$
G_k=\langle a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{k+1}\, |\, a_{i+1}a_ia_{i+1}^{-1}=a_i^2, i=1,2,\ldots,k\rangle.
$$
These groups, probably, were studied before; is there a name for these groups? One specific question:

**Question:** Are the groups $G_k$ linear?

Comment: Let me suggest that you review our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). As currently written, your post is a bare problem statement with no context, and you may have seen already that such posts attract down votes and close votes.

Comment: I don't have a specific context. The properties of Baumslag-Solitar groups are studied in graduate courses on group theory. It just seems interesting to me what happens when we iterate the construction. I was not able to find a reference dealing with such groups.

Comment: Could you specify what $G_k$ linear means?

Comment: At least over fields of zero characteristic, it is nonlinear once $k>1$. I do not know about their residual finiteness.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @SteveD: No, but this is quite straightforward using the Jordan normal forms.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: ok I'll think on it. That seems quite involved, since there are certainly nontrivial representations, but I'll try to work it out.

Comment: For $k>1$, $a_1^{2^{2^n}}=a_3^na_2a_3^{-n}a_1a_3^na_2^{-1}a_3^{-n}$. If $a_i$ are matrices, then the coefficients in $a_1^{2^{2^n}}$ grow at least $2^{2^n}$, what is not possible for $a_3^n$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Could you write an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @QMath: I already promised to write several answers. You can write your own answer and accept it, that would be totally fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The groups $G_k$ are not linear for $k>1$. This follows from the remark of Moishe Kohan. The relations $a_2a_1a_2^{-1}=a_1^2$ and $a_3a_2a_3^{-1}=a_2^2$ imply the relation $a^{2^{2^n}}_1=a^{n}_3a_2a^{−n}_3a_1a^{n}_3a^{−1}_2a^{−n}_3$. If we assume that $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are matrices, then the coefficients in $a^{2^{2^n}}_1$ grow at least as $2^{2^n}$, what is not possible for $a^n_3$.